# jQuery slide[Down/Up] with Fade[In/Out]

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, jquery-slide-effects

### Goal:

My goal is to use jQuery's `slideDown` with `FadeIn` or `slideUp` with `FadeOut`. I found several Google and StackOverflow search results to lead me to use the `slide[Down/Up]` with `animate({opacity: [1/0]},{queue: false})`.

I have 3 buttons, `Show 1`, `Show 2` and `All` and two divs `Div1` and `Div2`. On initial page load all divs show. When a user clicks on `Show 1` `Div2` should hide and fade, which it does.

### Problem:

My problem is while an `Div2` is animating the `slideUp` with `opacity: 0` and a user clicks on `Show 2` which should hide `Div1` and show `Div2` some dirty inline styles are stuck on the object which throws off the full effect desired.

### Examples:

Without an example most questions are useless :)  See the JSFiddle example I made and click on the buttons repeatedly.

http://jsfiddle.net/RoLYroLLs/bkWrH/

I know that using `stop` is why the styles are 'stuck' on the object. I need the `stop` so the object can hide/show, depending on the button clicked.

Is there another approach to this that I am not seeing?

Comment: Have you tried using combinations of `true,false / true, true, false / true` in the `.stop()` as arguments to see if any of those are the intended effects you want?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy yes I have. `true, true` and `false, true` have the issue that, due to the 2nd param, it takes you to the last frame of the animation sequence. What I prefer is that the new animation start from whatever point it was at when the user clicks any other button. `true, false` has the issue where the object that was hiding and now needs to be shown stays at the height which it is at, if still visible, when the user clicks on another button.

Comment: Yeah, that's basically what I figured your response would be. I think the only option you have is to create your own custom FX :/

Comment: Dang. I'm trying to dissect jquery-ui's accordion effect. Maybe I can have each as it's own accordion so i can show more than one at a time, but I don't want the styles, nor have to'undo' the styles it adds.

Comment: do you -need- jQuery-ui.css? if not, just don't include it.

Comment: Unfortunately I need it. I can go about separating the jquery-ui css to not include it for this one or possible other page, but make sure it's included in others. Too much work if you ask me.